# Const Char * becoming corrupted

Tags: c++

I have a superclass which sets a `const char *` member to the text "`V9k6FmI6Lw`" in its constructor.

However when the subclass reads this member it ends up being `"org: \200\201\360\210"`

Why is this?

The code of program:

```
Struct Json {
   std::string objectId;
}

class Super {

     const char * objectId;

  Super( Json value) {
      objectId = value.objectId.c_str();
  }
}

class Duper : public Super {
   Duper (Json value) : Super(value) {
   }

   void doSomething() {
      std::cout << "Object Id is : " << objectId;
   }
}

int main (){
   Json value { "V9k6FmI6Lw" };

   Duper object(value);
   object.doSomething();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in your program. If you want help on this then post the code of the program.

Comment: I have put psuedo code above

Comment: @JamesCampbell The problem is that the string `value.objectId` has been destroyed and therefore the pointer you have stored in your class is no longer valid. Don't mess with pointers, just replace `const char * objectId;` with `std::string objectId;` and remove `.c_str();`.

Comment: The question is now fine. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: Correct me if I am long but this line, "Duper (Json value) : Super(value)" , dosn't that call the super ctor ? or am I misunderstanding C.

Comment: now it does, after you corrected it :)

Comment: yes :) I had typed it out incorrect, something must be corrupting the memory. As the String that is usually given to objectID is actually returned from a function so may be going out of scope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Super` constructor takes a `JSON` by copy, i.e. inside the constructor you are working with a temporary copy of the object you create inside `main()`. You then store a pointer to the character sequence inside the string inside that temporary, so it's essentially a pointer into a temporary stack variable. After the constructor has finished, the `JSON` and the `string` inside it have been destroyed, leaving you with a pointer to *somwehere*, i.e. to some mfreed memory you do not own any more. No wonder the next time you dereference it, there is something else at that location, whatver got put there.

In this special case you can fix that by taking the `JSON` by reference in both constructors. However, you then have to make sure the `Super` and `Duper` objects never outlive the `JSON` objects from which they are constructed. If they do, you will have to store a copy of the `JSON` or the string inside it.

Comment: Would using strcpy work ? So I could copy the contents of the string inside of the JSON Object to my class ?

Comment: yes and no. It would work only if you create a buffer first where you can strcpy to. You'd have to manage the buffer manually (`new[]`, `delete[]`), wich would be too much of an effort, since `std::string` is just made for that task. Make the member objetc a `std::string` and copy the `objectId` out of the `JSON` parameter. All the memory management and strcpy'ing will be done for you automatically and correctly.

Comment: Thank you :) one last question, is it safe to say I should just use std::String everywhere ? or is this bad practice.

Comment: I'd say *almost* everything. There are times where performance and/or memory profiling hints you to not use `std::string`. But normally it's more comfortable and safe and maintainable than using `const char*`

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is, that you're passing the JSON object by value. So every time you pass the JSON object to a constructor of Duper and Super the object gets copied by the default copy constructor. Therefore the internal string member gets copied too and the pointer to the string is a different than the one in the main method. You can handle this by passing the JSON object by reference or by storing the string in Super with a std::string object.